# How to auto rotate screen in yocto linux for wayland compositor using services like sway or hikari, but not weston

Tags: yocto, autorotate, screen-rotation

Auto rotation is not working on yocto linux with service weston.
So can anyone suggest as how to achieve screen auto rotation using other services like
sway or hikari.

I am okay with using any service to achieve this except weston.

Comment: I'm about 99% sure that sway has no native auto-rotation, but it is not hard to add it. Keep monitoring your acceleromete/gyroscope (or whatever should trigger the rotation), and when there is a change, you can send an IPC message to sway to rotate the screen, either with swaymsg, or through socket. With swaymsg this would be something like `swaymsg 'output $DISPLAYNAME transform 90'` to rotate by 90 degree. Sway, sway-ipc (for socket communication) and sway-output man pages are the relevant ones.